# Use .htaccess to limit access based on referrer?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, user-agent, referrer

I want to use .htaccess rules to beef up security for Wordpress my blog. Basically, I want to forbid the connection when:

- useragent is empty
- referrer string is empty
- referrer string to a few selected php files is NOT from my domain

I've come up with the following code. Am I on the right track? If not, please suggest what I should do to fix it. Thank you!

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^$
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} wp-comments-post\.php* [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} wp-admin\.php* [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} wp-login\.php* [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !.*example.com.* [NC]
    RewriteRule . - [R=403,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I think you need to add a few `[OR]`s. Please note that some software and proxies remove the referrer header.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, methinks I've figured it out. I was able to come up with a snippet that I think is working:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} wp-comments-post\.php* [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} wp-admin\.php* [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} wp-login\.php*
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !.*tambnguyen.com.* 
    RewriteRule . - [R=403,L]
</IfModule>
```

It looks like I can't access http://tambnguyen.com/wp-admin/ using a new browser window/tab when I'm not logged in. I can click on a secret link to log in. Also, once I'm logged in, I can visit http://tambnguyen.com/wp-admin/ with no problem.